# DOM element in mdTab not updated with angular .css method

Tags: html, angularjs, tabs, angular-material

I got progress bar in my table where I show how many hours has been spend on project. When I click on some tab, currentTab method is fired to get data from database and after I promise is resolved my TimeService function is fired also to calculate hours for progress bar, but when `angular .css()` is reached it doesnt update my progress bar at all and I dont know why since it definitely 100% working code. Is there some feature in mdTabs which prevent this?

HTML code below, I deleted plenty of stuff to make it more readable

```
<md-tab label="Testing" md-on-select="currentTab('Testing')">
<md-content class="md-padding">
    <table id="projects-active" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Estimated time</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="project in projects.Data">
                <td>{{project.Id}}</td>
                <td>{{project.Name}}</td>
                <td>{{project.Description}}</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="progress-group">
                        <div class="progress sm">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped" id="progress-bar-pId-{{project.Id}}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>{{project.Status}}</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="box-footer clearfix">
        <ul uib-pagination total-items="totalItems"
            items-per-page="maxSize"
            ng-model="currentPage"
            max-size="maxSize"
            class="pagination-sm"
            boundary-links="true"
            num-pages="pages"
            ng-change="setPage(currentPage, 'Testing')"></ul>
    </div>
</md-content>
```

Here is my function in TimeService modul

```
projectProgressArray: function (array) {

var items = array.Data;

angular.forEach(items, function (key, value) {
    var id = key.Id;
    var maxTime = key.EstimatedTime;
    var currentTime = key.TimeSpend;
    var percentageComplete = Math.round(((currentTime / maxTime) * PERCENTAGE) * 100) / 100;
    if (!("#progress-bar-pId-" + id).length == 0) {
        angular.element("#progress-bar-pId-" + id).css("width", percentageComplete + "%");
        if (percentageComplete > 100) {
            angular.element("#progress-bar-pId-" + id).removeClass("progress-bar-success");
            angular.element("#progress-bar-pId-" + id).addClass("progress-bar-danger");
        }
    }  
});
```

Here is my controller function where I fetch data to my data tables

```
var MAX_SIZE_PER_PAGE = 5;

$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.maxSize = MAX_SIZE_PER_PAGE;
$scope.pages = 0;
$scope.totalItems = 0;

$scope.setPage = function (pageNo, status) {
$scope.currentPage = pageNo;
$scope.projects = ProjectService.queryPaged({ pageSize: $scope.maxSize, pageNumber: $scope.currentPage, status: status });

    $scope.projects.$promise.then(function (data) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            TimeService.projectProgressArray($scope.projects);
        }, 0);
    });
};
$scope.currentTab = function (status) {

    $scope.projects = ProjectService.queryPaged({ pageSize: $scope.maxSize, pageNumber: 1, status: status });
    $scope.projects.$promise.then(function (data) {
        $scope.totalItems = data.TotalCount;

        setTimeout(function () {
            TimeService.projectProgressArray($scope.projects);
        }, 0);
    });
}
```

**UPDATE:** I added image where i copy progress bars outside of `md-tab` to show its working outside of `md-tabs` but not inside it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some time of I found out that I cannot manipulate with `css` in `Angular material` using `angular.element().css()` method. I had to edit my TimeService method where I created array filled with information about single progress bar per project and send it back to my controller and use `ng-style`
to manipulate with my css inside ng-material DOM

```
 projectProgressArray: function (array) {
            var progressBarArray = [];

            var items = array.Data;

            angular.forEach(items, function (key, value) {
                var progressBar = {
                    projectId: null,
                    percentage: null,
                    barClass: null
                }

                var id = key.Id;
                var maxTime = key.EstimatedTime;
                var currentTime = key.TimeSpend;
                var percentageComplete = Math.round(((currentTime / maxTime) * PERCENTAGE) * 100) / 100;

                progressBar.projectId = id;
                progressBar.percentage = percentageComplete + "%";

                if (!("#progress-bar-pId-" + id).length == 0) {
                    if (percentageComplete > 100) {
                        progressBar.barClass = "progress-bar-danger";
                    }
                    else {
                        progressBar.barClass = "progress-bar-success";
                    }
                }
                progressBarArray.push(progressBar);
            });
            return progressBarArray;
```

Reworked HTML binding

```
<div class="progress-group">
<div class="progress sm" ng-repeat="item in progressBars" ng-hide="item.projectId != project.Id">
    <div ng-class="{'progress-bar-success': item.barClass == 'progress-bar-success',
                                                            'progress-bar-danger': item.barClass == 'progress-bar-danger' }"
         class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped" id="progress-bar-pId-{{project.Id}}"
         ng-style="{'width':item.percentage}">
    </div>
</div>
```